Assign intrinsic array property of object in javascript
I've worked out a different way of getting around this for my immediate problem, but I can't resist asking the question for the aficionados out there!  This is an advanced question.
So just about everything (other than primitive types) in javascript is an object, including an array. As such, you can assign properties to it.
var arr = [];
arr[1] = 42;
arr[5] = 666;
arr.firstName = 'ebenezer';
arr.lastName = 'scrooge';

var arr2 = [];
arr2.firstName = 'daffy';
arr2.lastName = 'duck';

var obj2 = {};
obj2.firstName = 'smokey';
obj2.lastName = 'bear';

I'm describing the array property of arr as the 'intrinsic' array:
arr[1]   // returns 42

So my question is: can I assign just the intrinsic array (the whole array but not any other properties) to the other objects, eg:
arr2.arrayProp (??something like this??) = arr[];
arr2[1] // want it to return 42
arr2.firstName // want it to return 'daffy'

obj2[](??something like this??) = arr[];
obj2[1] // want it to return 42
obj2.firstName // want it to return 'smokey'

Clearly if I assign the whole array or object, it just creates a reference to the original object and all its properties.
I'm wondering if there is some 'under the hood' way to assign just the array property.
I think the answer is 'no', but surprise me.
EDIT
OK, this has been very illuminating. I've awarded the answer to @HauWu since you made a good contribution.
In the end, the whole premise of my question stands or falls on this:
Given
arr[1] = 'intIndex'; 
arr['1'] = 'strIndex';
console.log(arr[1], arr['1']);

Do you get
   A: intIndex    strIndex
or B: strIndex    strIndex

It turns out that you get B, but up until I intended to correct @HauWu and checked it first, I could have sworn that it was A.  How could I misunderstand things so badly?
I went and checked the Mozilla documentation on Array (which I, perhaps mistakely, generally consider authoritative), and it says this:

Array objects cannot use arbitrary strings as element indexes (as in
an associative array) but must use nonnegative integers (or their
respective string form). Setting or accessing via non-integers will
not set or retrieve an element from the array list itself, but will
set or access a variable associated with that array's object property
collection. The array's object properties and list of array elements
are separate, and the array's traversal and mutation operations cannot
be applied to these named properties.

This is the fourth time I've looked at it, and I've only just noticed the part where it says: (or their respective string form).
Rather I saw the part where it said:  Setting or accessing via non-integers will not set or retrieve an element from the array list itself, but will set or access a variable associated with that array's object property collection.
This was the root of my misunderstanding - that array elements were partitioned off from object properties and held in a special internal construct accessed only by integer index, where properties were accessed only by string index.
To digress for a minute, arrays are extremely important in any programming language because they are comprised of fixed sized chunks, so a simple multiply operation will get you the element you want. Array reference is usually an order of magnitude faster than dictionary (hashed collection) reference, so this distinction is extremely important.
It's now hard to know exactly what form of lookup is used internally in Javascript.
Off to look at the ECMAScript specification. Arrays are classified as an exotic object and gives special treatment of integer-equivalent keys, using CanonicalNumericIndexString and ToIndex internally to evaluate the integer-equivalent keys.
I did run some performance tests to check the lookup speed of array indexed data versus text keyed data, but I don't fully trust the results due to possible JIT compiler optimisation. Will post results back here if I get to a point where I think they are reliable.
However I am pretty sure there is some significant caching going on with property keys, and array integer-equivalent keys in particular (excellent article here on the caching in Google's V8 implementation).
FINAL EDIT: It does appear that running benchmark code is somewhat of a fool's errand. JS compilers are optimised in very strange ways that may not make sense at first glance, but are no doubt ruthlessly benchmarked and optimised against statistically significant common high workloads.
This article gives a great rundown of performance consideration by someone who is clearly across it all. In particular, it is clear that JS can switch without warning between various optimisaton models in response to activity in the data.
So, to summarise:

array elements in js are stored as object properties having the string equivalent of the integer index as a key
js does optimise for array lookup performance, and may even construct a purely internal classic in-memory lookup array of memory locations for the elements. This is not part of the specification and therefore may be implementation-dependent.

To answer the original question, there is no way of copying the array elements as a single assignment, because they are simply object properties. The accepted answer offered a reasonable workaround.
I have heard it said that Javascript is very closely related to LISP - a language that was used decades ago for AI research. I think this reinforces that view very much - Javascript at its root simply passes around from place to place objects extensible with properties. There is an obligatory amount of primitive type support and then everything else is simply syntactic sugar and some judicious optimisation.
I offer the following for your amusement courtesy of the commenters to Dreaming In Javascript:
var foo = { toString: function() { return “hello”; } };
var hi = { hello: “hola” };

hi[foo]; // returns “hola”

and
var A=[];
A[NaN]=”notanumerbery”;
console.log(A[parseInt(“:P”)]);
// notanumerbery


wouldn't that be achieved by simply arr2 = arr and obj2 = arr?

No, there is no specific language structure for this. You can only do this with iteration and some if check over all object's items.

There is no "the array property". What makes an array be an array is that it has non-negative integer properties. That and that inherits from the global Array but your question assumes that the array object "hides" a single thing which is the real array. But if that were true, then you reach infinite regression logically - that "hidden array' must still be an object. Because it's not primitive. Therefore, if it's an object it must itself have a "hidden array" property. Which must be an object. Repeat ad infinitum.

At any rate, this question seems to be an XY problem.  It's trying trying to find a non-existing Y. But the original problem X isn't clear. What are you trying to do that you think "the array property" would solve? Clone an array? Copy over only the indexes? What exactly should those entail, either? What should happen if ["a", "b", "c"] and [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] (different lengths) are the inputs to whatever X is? What about empty slots, e.g., ["a", ,  "c"] and [ , 2, 3]?

Could this be what you wanted?


var arr = [];
arr[1] = 42;
arr[5] = 666;
arr.firstName = 'ebenezer';
arr.lastName = 'scrooge';

var arr2 = [];
arr2.firstName = 'daffy';
arr2.lastName = 'duck';

var obj2 = {};
obj2.firstName = 'smokey';
obj2.lastName = 'bear';

// assign only array indices
Object.assign(arr2, [...arr]);
Object.assign(obj2, [...arr]);

console.log('arr2[1] -> ' + arr2[1]);
console.log('arr2.firstName -> ' + arr2.firstName);
console.log('obj2[1] -> ' + obj2[1]);
console.log('obj2.firstName -> ' + obj2.firstName);



However, instead of [empty, 42, empty x 3, 666], it creates all missing indices: [undefined, 42, undefined, undefined, undefined, 666]. If that's not what you wanted, the following approach could avoid this:


function assignArrayIndices(target, source) {
  source.forEach((value, key) => target[key] = value);
}

var arr = [];
arr[1] = 42;
arr[5] = 666;
arr.firstName = 'ebenezer';
arr.lastName = 'scrooge';

var arr2 = [];
arr2.firstName = 'daffy';
arr2.lastName = 'duck';

var obj2 = {};
obj2.firstName = 'smokey';
obj2.lastName = 'bear';

// assign only array indices
assignArrayIndices(arr2, arr);
assignArrayIndices(obj2, arr);


console.log('arr2[1] -> ' + arr2[1]);
console.log('arr2.firstName -> ' + arr2.firstName);
console.log('obj2[1] -> ' + obj2[1]);
console.log('obj2.firstName -> ' + obj2.firstName);

console.log('arr2 -> ' + arr2);
console.log('obj2 -> ' + obj2);




No need to use Object.keys() and then filter to get the array indexes. arr.entries() will give you an iterator with key/values (but it also goes over empty slots) while arr.forEach() will skip the empty slots and only go over existing array indexes. The whole Object.keys(source).filter(key => /^(0|[1-9]\d*)$/.test(key)).forEach(key => target[key] = source[key]); is just source.forEach(key => target[key] = source[key]); with extra steps. At best it can be [].forEach.call(source, key => target[key] = source[key]) which will work on any array-like.

Oops, I messed up the parameters. That should be source.forEach((_, key) => target[key] = source[key]) if using an array. Or even source.forEach((value, key) => target[key] = value]). Similarly for using the array forEach() on an array like

@VLAZ Good call, I've edited my answer according to your suggestion. It does look much cleaner now.

Sorry, I'm really busy today, will comment more tomorrow. I'd actually like to see the original solution and the cleaner one.  This is a 'fun' question whose only purpose is learning. The reason I am assuming that there is an intrinsic array is that you can do arr[1] = 'eeney'; arr['1'] = 'meeney'; and these are two separate properties. So I'm assuming that internally the integer keys are completely separate to the string keys. I was thinking of dot notation, but I suppose in bracket notation the two are equivalent so it makes sense that the array can't be referenced independently.

@BenMcIntyre I see what confused you now. In JavaScript object keys (except for Symbols) including array indices are all strings. However, arr['1'] and arr[1] are the same but arr['1'] and arr['01'] are not.

@BenMcIntyre instead of assuming wrong and then asking questions based on those wrong assumptions, it's more effective to avoid the assume wrong step. If you want to know how arrays and/or objects and/or keys work, ask about that. Or research that, since it's a topic well-covered on SO and elsewhere.

Added some comments and research findings.
